# Heat only works when engine is revving and at full power

Tags: ac, chrysler, heater

On a 2004 Chrysler Sebring, the air only works when turned up to maximum power. At any of the 3 levels below that, no air comes out.

Additionally, when the heat is on, it only blows hot air while the engine is revving. When I release the gas, I can start to feel the air gradually cool down (especially at stop lights). This was not much fun in the winter - I haven't tested yet to see if the AC works the same way now that it's warm out.

What could be causing this, and would the parts be expensive and labor time-consuming?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As for the blower only working on max, that screams [resistor pack](http://www.rockauto.com/catalog/raframecatalog.php?carcode=1424405&parttype=6557&partkey=2194770&a=FRc1424405k2194770-2899550).  It's usually in the passenger foot well near the blower motor itself.  [Sounds like](http://www.chryslerforum.com/forum/chrysler-sebring-14/blower-motor-resistor-diy-2004-sebring-sedan-8772/) it's held in by two 8mm bolts in your case.  Shouldn't be too terrible of a job, but you might want to avoid it if you've got back or neck problems.  I usually put the seat back down as far as it will go and lay down facing forward and pull myself up under the dash.  If you've been running the blower exclusively on high for a while, it might be the next thing to go out.  Last time I changed a resistor, the blower worked for a couple days then died.  That was a little more involved, but still doable if you don't mind being upside down in a tight space.

As for the temperature falling off, the two things that come to mind for me are maybe a clogged heater core and / or thermostat.  What are your engine temps like?

Comment: This was correct, by the way. I finally got around to this. Replaced the blower motor resistor, and now the hot and cool air both work at all 4 levels. As you said, not a difficult job but an awkward position. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The heat problem sounds like poor coolant circulation, possibly due to low fluid level or partial clogging.